# Put a shape outside the canvas, without increase their size

Tags: html, css, position

I have a little issue positioning an element outside the canvas to star an animation from the outside. An example bellow.

```css
.square {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #555;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="square"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is a reference image about the expected start position of the element (red dotted box).

[image: Start position image reference]

**Anyone know how to configure the css related to the object to position it outside the canvas without increases their (canvas) size?**

Hopefully without deactivate the scroll bar (for example to increase the left side of the canvas) and not over the canvas (to keeping it scrollable and not relative)

*I thought this is the simplest question ever, but i couldn't find on the web, hope to be helpful to someone, thanks!*

Comment: position: fixed.

Comment: The position fixed  always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled. The goal its to put IN the canvas (keeping it scrollable) and not over it.